# How to tell customer that you have a tight schedule without sounding rude?

Tags: word-choice, politeness

I would like to explain a customer that during the next two months we will be very busy with a tight schedule, but I don't want to sound rude or put him in a rush, as I only have certain day available within this month.

What would you say?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm afraid writing advice is off topic here. This site provides specific answers to specific questions, not whole sentences for your particular situation.

Comment: You could always add that you *wish* you had the ability to be more flexible within your obligations.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much like you said it -
"I'm very/really sorry but during the next two months we will be very busy with a tight schedule, hence please try to reschedule (your appointment or whatever). Sorry for the inconvenience/Any inconvenience caused is deeply regretted."